# How to prove that $x_{n+1} - x_n > x_n - x_{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ derivable with  $f(0) > 0 $, $f'(x) > 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $x_0 = 0 $ and $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$. Prove that $x_{n+1} - x_n > x_n - x_{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I deduced that $f$ is increasing (using that $f(0) > 0 $, $f'(x) > 1$) and i get something like $x_n - x_{n - 1} > 0$ and $x_{n+1} - x_n > 0$ (i don't know if this helps me, but is similar to the result). So what else i can infer.

Comment: Hint: Plug in the definition for $x_n$ on one side of the assertion then see if you can apply the mean value theorem and use that the derivative is greater than $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* $x_1 - x_0 = f(0) - 0 > 0$. Now use induction and apply the mean-value theorem to
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n = f(x_n) - f(x_{n-1})
$$
and use that $f'(x) > 1$.

Comment: Oh! thanks i didn´t see the possibility to use MVT (but it was evident). Indeed i don't need to use that $f(x_0) > 0$ because it is given.

Comment: @Fredgrub: One needs that $x_1 > x_0$, otherwise the sequence is decreasing, and all inequalities are the other way around.

Comment: aahhh!! i get it now!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f(x)-x$ is strictly increasing because its derivative is $f'(x)-1$. Moreover, since $f(0)-0>0$, it is also strictly positive. This means that $f(x)>x$ for all $x$, which implies that $x_n$ is an increasing sequence. Since $x_{n-1}<x_{n}$, $$x_n-x_{n-1}=f(x_{n-1})-x_{n-1}<f(x_n)-x_n =x_{n+1}-x_n$$

Comment: good way too. thanks!